# Android FileSystem layout on Playbook

Tags: android, filesystems, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I'm unfamiliar with how the Android player sees the file system. Previously in Air apps I would create a directory in Documents to save my app's files in. What directory should I use for storage in an Android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Blackberry emulator for Android apps copes perfectly fine with storing data to the external storage through [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29).

Note that these are both external storage. Usually you would just store data into the private data folder. You can find [more information about the storage options on Android here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).